# CollapsingToolBarLayout and statusbar transparency

Tags: android, transparency, statusbar, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I'm trying make my status bar overlay over my content, which includes a CollapsingToolBarLayout ( inside CoordinatorLayout obviously ). So this is my current afford to make it happen;

a sampling from my layout is in the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="240dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/employeeAvatarImageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />
```

And in the source, I did the following;

```
    private void setupDecorView() {
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);        
    }

    private void setupStatusBar() {
        Window window = getWindow();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
          window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
         window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            window.setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor("#3F51B5FF"));                 

        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS,   WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
           window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
        } else {
        }
    }
```

And I keep getting this image in the initial looking. Status bar is having is original color - no transparency.

[image]

However, when I first attemp to scroll, the status bar gets the transparent color I've set and want like the following:

[image]

So what might be the problem? Any ideas?

Comment: It looks to me as though your content starts out as laid out below your status bar, then scrolls into it.  Why do you have `android:fitsSystemWindows="false"` on your `CollapsingToolbarLayout`? What happens if you set that to `"true"`?

Comment: Yes it seems so. That's why I set android:fitsSystemWindows="false" to make sure the content doesn't laid out below status bar. So making it fit with system decorations don't help.